# Use ng if to check for a string value in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

How can I use `ngIf` to check a variable for a string value, in ionic 5.

Tried the following for example but not working

```
<div *ngIf="sentData=='Eedc_prepaid_custom'"> 

  <p>KLSKLS</p> 
</div>
```

Meanwhile if I echo {{sentData}} it displays `Eedc_prepaid_custom` but the condition above is not working.

Can anyone help?

Comment: That ngIf condition seems fine, are you sure the string is exactly the same as in the condition? It might have different upper/lower cases or trailing empty characters?

Comment: make sure that sendData is NOT an array, e.g. is `sendData =['Eedc_prepaid_custom']`, `{{sendData}}` show `Eedc_prepaid_custom` (the comparision must be `*ngIf="sendData[0]=='Eedc_prepaid_custom'`

Comment: no its not an array, its just a string value..a variable with a value in it

Comment: I have found that, in Ionic, some trivial things ake a difference.  For example, in my current project, <code><ion-item *ngIf = "...</code> compiles fine, but <code><ion-item *ngIf="</code> does not (spaces/no spaces around the '=").  Also, try === for the comparison instead of == I know it makes no sense, but there you are.